# wpf: Label in toolbar gets clipped

Tags: wpf

If I create a toolbar with a label and a button like this:

```
    <ToolBar Height="26" >
        <Label>Hi mom</Label>
        <Button>Press me</Button>
    </ToolBar>
```

The button text centers on the toolbar and does not get clipped.

[image]

How can I make the text on the label appear with an equal apperance as the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Here's how to do it with a Label (fixed Left/Right padding)

```
<ToolBar Height="26" >
    <Label Padding="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hi mom</Label>
    <Button>Press me</Button>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: Close (and enough for a cigar), but you have to do something like this with the padding:             <Label Padding="2 2 3 0" VerticalAlignment="Center">Hi mom</Label>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the TextBlock version:

This creates a textblock which creates a similar apperance as the button:

```
        <TextBlock Margin="2 2 3 0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Press Me"></TextBlock>
```